# При скачивании из Телеграм изображение сильно уменьшается. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, изображения, разрешение

Пытаюсь сделать телеграм-бота. При скачивании изображений от пользователя размер картинки сильно уменьшается.
Скачиваю так

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def handle_docs_image(message):
   file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
   downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)    
   src = 'E:/111/' + file_info.file_path
   with open(src, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(downloaded_file)    
   bot.reply_to(message, "Я возьму")
```

При этом если сразу же отправить эту картинку пользователю обратно

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, idphoto)
```

качество такое же, как у исходной.
Пыталась скачать с помощью imread - тот же результат((

```
url = f'http://api.telegram.org/file/bot{token}/{file_info.file_path}'
im2 = imread(url)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать, чтоб получить нормальный размер картинки

UPD с помощью wget.download то же самое

Comment: Пробовали `message.photo[1]` или даже `message.photo[2]`? Вообще посмотрите, что там в массиве хранится. Насколько помню, там одно и то же изображение в разных размерах сохраняется для сообщения. Говорю, как в своем случае поступал.

Comment: нет, не пробовала. Спасибо за идею. ВОзможно, позже попробую. Решила пока по-другому - если отправляют не как картинку, а как файл, и принимаю как файл - всё нормально, сохраняется в исходном размере

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! Всё теперь работает правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто берите самый последний элемент из массива фотографий. Как Вам уже сказали, в массиве хранятся разные размеры этой фотографии, чем "первее" элемент массива - тем хуже качество.

```py
file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.